# Login to a web site using python and submitting a code

Tags: python

I have never written a web scraper or crawler, and needed to write a python code that allows me to login to a web site and then write a code and submit it. I tried using "requests" but couldn't figure it out.I wish someone could possibly help. Here's the html code parts, for the login:

```
<form class="form-signin" action="login2.php" method="post">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">sign in now</h2>
    <div class="login-wrap">
        <div class="user-login-info">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pseudo" placeholder="Username" autofocus="" required="">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="mdp" placeholder="Password" required="">
        </div>

            <span class="pull-right">
                <a class="" href="passoubli.php"> Mot de passe oubli� ?</a>

            </span>

        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-login btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
```

and here's the code form:

```
<form name="sp" id="sp" method="post" action="verifi107.php">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="[ XXXXXXXX ]" maxlength="10" id="ext_frm_code2" name="RECALL" required="">



            <center><button class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" type="submit" style="width:190px">Valider</button></center>
       </form>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look over [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) is pretty easy to use and will do the work you may want to do.

It works with some lenguages and almost all browsers and have [python bindings](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/).